# Failed to install filterpy

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python, and I have trouble installing packages...

Environment: pip version: 24.0, python version: 3.8, OS: Win 10.0.19045.4170

At first, I tried to install Real-ESRGAN following the instruction:

```
# Install basicsr - https://github.com/xinntao/BasicSR
# We use BasicSR for both training and inference
pip install basicsr
# facexlib and gfpgan are for face enhancement
pip install facexlib
pip install gfpgan
pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py develop
```

The installation of basicsr was successful, but after typing `pip install facexlib`, an error occured:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Collecting facexlib
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/36/7b/2147339dafe1c4800514c9c21ee4444f8b419ce51dfc7695220a8e0069a6/facexlib-0.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting filterpy (from facexlib)
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/f6/1d/ac8914360460fafa1990890259b7fa5ef7ba4cd59014e782e4ab3ab144d8/filterpy-1.4.5.zip (177 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Initialize\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-c2s08o0f\filterpy_4d567f49cadb405fa28fab3d300eebf4\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          import filterpy
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filterpy'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

It seems that I should install filterpy first. So I typed `pip install filterpy`, but almost the same error occurred:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
Collecting filterpy
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/f6/1d/ac8914360460fafa1990890259b7fa5ef7ba4cd59014e782e4ab3ab144d8/filterpy-1.4.5.zip (177 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Initialize\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gcrncr7c\filterpy_b52f458dbe1640e1b0dfbaaa48b8d46a\setup.py", line 4, in <module>
          import filterpy
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filterpy'
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I got confused because it said "No module named 'filterpy'" when installing filterpy. I have tried to change the source of pip many times by `pip config set global.index-url http://mirrors.cloud.tencent.com/pypi/simple`.

I also tried to download the zip from pypi and used `pip install D:\...\filterpy-1.4.5.zip`, but just encountered the same error...

I tried to download the source code from github and used `python setup.py install`, and it said

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 4, in <module>
    import filterpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filterpy'
```

Now I have no idea about what to do next...

I want to install the filterpy package correctly, and then install other requirements of Real-ESRGAN. Glad to hear any suggestion on this post, my English grammar and other aspects :)